# Has something changed in the Facebook API to post photos to wall?

Tags: php, facebook

Till a few hours back the code below was uploading a photo to the application album of the user and also posting it to the wall. Now suddenly the wall post is not happening anymore:

```
$args = array('message' => "text message");
$args['image'] = '@' . "actual path to image on server";
$args['link'] = 'link to the FB app';

$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If it worked and then stopped working, you should do the following:

1. Check the API status http://developers.facebook.com/live_status
2. Search the bugs https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/
3. If found, subscribe to it
4. If not found, add a bug

Comment: Thanks. I am doing this now. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I found the solution though I am not sure what the logic behind it is.

Comment: The photos stop coming on the wall if the no.of photos in the application album cross a certain number (I am not sure of the number). I deleted the application album and ran the app again and it was able to post to the wall as well.

Comment: Is your access token valid and does it have the appropriate permissions?

Comment: Maybe 200 is the limit per album?